# Getting Parser Error when adding Razor to HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to add razor to my HTML but now I am getting a Parser Error and do not understand why I get this error:

**HTML:**

```
@model ServingTeam.DAL.Members
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Member";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMember", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>
            New Member</h2>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="memberForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label" />
            Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name", type = "text", required = "required " })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Surname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Surname", type = "text", required = "required " })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Cell</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cell, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Cell", type = "text" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter email address", type = "email", required = "required " })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                    Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script>
    $("#memberForm").validate();
</script>
```

This is the error I get:
***Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?*** All works fine when I remove Razor.

Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure that the error doesn't lie within the layout-file?

Comment: No my other pages works fine even with Razor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find one error in your markup, don't know if it has anything to do with your current error though.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="memberForm">
 </form>
```

the using(Html.BeginForm) will actually create a form for you, now you have a form within the form, which is not wizely

```
<label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label" />
        Name</label>
```

There you go. the label gets cancelled out twice.

Comment: I have another page that have a form inside the using(Html.Form) and it works perfectly. That is the reason I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Didnt say it wouldnt work, just said it wasnt wizely;)